# AZURE AD Certificate Based Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory

is there a way to know using Advanced Hunting queries(KQL) whether a user logged in using certificate based authentication?
do we see these kind of data in AAdSignInEventsBeta?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to get the certificate-based authentication logs in **Azure AD** with **KQL**:

**Create Log Analytics workspaces**, like below.

Go to **Azure Portal > Log Analytics workspaces > Create Log Analytics workspace**.

[image]

Once create the **Log Analytics workspaces**, send all **Azure AD** **Sign-in logs** to **Log Analytics workspaces**, like below.

Go to **Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting. **

[image]

Check the **Azure AD** sign-in logs, like below.

Open your **Log Analytics workspaces** > **Logs**.

Run the below **KQL** query to get the **Azure AD** sign-in logs.

```
SigninLogs
| where Category == "AuthenticationLogs"
| where Method == "Certificate"
```

Reference:
[Analyze activity logs using Azure Monitor logs - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-analyze-activity-logs-log-analytics).